# Error when installing an non-market application on android phones

Tags: android, deployment

I'm having a problem when installing my android program (built in Eclipse) on my Samsung galaxy S2 phone.
I uploaded the '.apk' file into my gmail and then using my galaxy to download and install it.
But after finishing the installation it appears 4 applications not 1 main application (I used 4 '.java' files in my program). When I click each application, my program still run well.
I exported with unsigned and singed key in Eclipse but the problem still happened.
So anyone can tell me how to solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned you are haivng 4 .java files and it appears 4 applications not 1 main application, so for that i am sure you have declared below tags in every `<activity>` tag, instead you just need to put the same tags inside the `<activity>` which is main activity:

```
 <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

In short, remove these tags from every `<activity>` tag except main activity.

Comment: @user1033121  just a quick suggestion, as per StackOverflow FAQ, you should accept answer whenever you find it useful. Anyway cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

When you will attach your samsung with your system and run the app on your phone directly instead of emulator as eclipse will automatically detect the android phone., the app get automatically installed in your samsung or you can download the software Kies.